# Magento 2 use of frontend_input_renderer for product custom attribute

Tags: magento2

I have created one attribute (CategoryPath) at product level using installer script, which holds the value of category full path of the product. This will update through the observer when we do some changes in category assignment on product page and save the product. It's working fine.

Now if I change the category hierarchy in admin from category screen and check the same product then that attribute won't display the updated category path fetching from DB, so I come to know that we could use "frontend_input_renderer" attribute property to display the value dynamically instead of saving into DB, but I could not able to find out how to use use it for the custom product attribute.

Can anybody help me on it.

Comment: Do you want to know how to update an existing custom attribute or do you want to know how to install the custom attribute and set the frontend input renderer at the same time?

Comment: I want to display the value of the product's selected categories full path in that attribute only in backend rather than save it into DB. I hope you understood.